# "/usr/bin/stat: Argument list too long" error

Tags: shell

I need to get the list of files(`.log/.lst`) present in a directory(`$logfolder`) whose creation date is in a specific `$year` and `$month`

```
stat  --format='%y %n'  $logfolder/* |
  grep "$year-$month-"|
  awk -F' ' '{print $4}'|
  grep 'log$\|lst$' > $archivepath/filesToArchive
```

This doesn't work when I query the command to a folder where there are too many files. I get the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/stat: Argument list too long
```

Comment: Your `grep` will catch both files with the date in the name and the `stat` date.

Comment: Your `awk` will miss files with spaces in the name.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
find "$logfolder" \( -name '*.log' -o -name '*lst' \) -printf "%TB\t%TY\t%p\n" |
     awk '$1==m && $2==y' m="$month" y="$year" | cut -f 3-
```

#### Explanation

By grouping the two `-name` calls in parentheses, you can combine them with the `-o` (or) flag. This will make `find` look for either `.log` or `.lst` files. The `-printf` (a GNU extension) prints the file's modification month (`%TB`), then its modification year (`%TY`) and then its path (`%p`), with a tab (`\t`) between each field.

The `awk` simply checks that the 1st field (the month) is the same as `$month` and the second is the same as `$year`.

The `cut` removes the first two fields (the month and year) and prints everything from the 3rd field on.

I tested the above by creating files modified in December 2012 (and set `$month` to "December" and `$year` to 2012):

```
$ touch -d "December 13 2012" {a,b,c}{.lst,.log}
$ touch c.lst a.log ## c.lst and a.log now have today's modification date.
$ find $logfolder \( -name '*.log' -o -name '*lst' \) -printf "%TB\t%TY\t%p\n" |
  awk '$1==m && $2==y' m="$month" y="$year" | cut -f 3-
./b.log
./c.log
./b.lst
./a.lst
```

(note that it assumes file and directory names don't contain newline characters).

Answer (score 3):

For a funny possibility, if your `find` handles `-newerXY`, use it! For example to get the files from year 1977 and month October:

```
find "$logfolder" \( -name '*.log' -o -name '*.lst' \) -newermt "1977-10-01" \! -newermt "1977-10-01 +1 month"
```

Done!

As you already have the variables `year` and `month` it's straightforward to write as:

```
find "$logfolder" \( -name '*.log' -o -name '*.lst' \) -newermt "$year-$month-01" \! -newermt "$year-$month-01 +1 month"
```

Only one `find` command! amazing!

Comment: +1 Since the OP's `stat` is of the GNU variant, his `find` more than likely supports `-newermt` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find $logfolder -type f -exec stat --format='%y %n' "{}" + |
  grep "$year-$month-"|
  awk -F' ' '{print $4}'|
  grep 'log$\|lst$' > $archivepath/filesToArchive
```

Comment: `grep "^$year-$month-"` so you don't the string in file names

Comment: @mtm: I only use `find` to fix the error `Argument list too long`. It's very hard to know exactly what the OP want.

Comment: No worries.. will comment on OP

Comment: `awk` can do `grep`'s job and more, you almost never need to pipe awk and grep together. Note that your last grep command is not portable/standard.

Answer (score 0):

`ls -lh *.log *.lst logfolder | grep year | grep month`